# SSRS : How to aggregate on certain values of a column?

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate

I have a column (Say PriceA) in SSRS which gets populated based of Expression.

**PriceA.value**

```
IIF((Fields!MOP.Value = "PRIV" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "FACI" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "GUAR" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "CASH"
OR Fields!MOP.Value = "CHRG" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "INV"), 

    IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value,"U/D",Fields!TtlPrice.Value), 

        IIF(Fields!elecadj.Value="0" AND Fields!elecadj2.Value="0", IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value,"U/D",IIF(Fields!MOP2.Value="0",Fields!Copay.Value,"")), 

            IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value,"U/D",Fields!PatientPayAmt.Value)
        )
    )
```

The Value in PriceA can be "U/D" or Zero or some value as "150.00". Now I want to display at the end of the report, an aggregate of the rows in that column, discarding the values $0.0 and "U/D".

How do I do that?

---

I also have another column where it shows values based off off 2 different expression, that I need to aggregate. That one is not working either.

**2ndPriceA_expression**

```
IIF((Fields!MOP.Value = "PRIV" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "FACI" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "GUAR" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "CASH"
OR Fields!MOP.Value = "CHRG" OR Fields!MOP.Value = "INV"), " ",

    IIF(Fields!elecadj.Value="0" AND  Fields!elecadj2.Value="0",

        IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value="0",Format(Fields!TtlPrice.Value,"C"),"U/D") , 

            IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value="0",Format(Fields!Payor1PaidAmt.Value,"C"),"U/D")
    )

)
```

**2ndPriceB_expression**

```
IIF(Fields!MOP2.Value<>"",
    IIF(Fields!elecadj.Value="0" and Fields!elecadj2.Value="0"
        ,IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value="1","U/D",Fields!Copay.Value)
        ,IIF(Fields!UDRx.Value="1"
            ,"U/D"
            ,IIF(Fields!elecadj2.Value="0"
                ,Fields!Copay.Value
                ,Fields!Payor2PaidAmt.Value
                )
            )
        )
," ")
```

I need to show aggregate of 2ndPriceA & 2ndPriceB in a 3rd cell. Sorry I'm 2 weeks new to SSRS.

Thanks in advance. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a SUM() of an IIF() expression that will filter out the values you don't want to SUM.